# Events doesn't work after updating them with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So let's assume that I have this simple code:

HTML:

```
<div id="test">Hello!</div>
<input type="submit" id="update_map" value="Update!" />
```

JQUERY:

```
$("#id").mouseover(function ()
{
    alert("TRUE");
});
```

So far everything works perfect, but when I'm updating the **test** div with that code:

```
$("#update_map").click(function ()
{
    $.post( "update_ajax.php", function( data ) {
        $( "#test" ).html( data );
        alert("Done!");
    });
});
```

But now, when I clicked on "Update!", and I'll move my mouse over the "test" div, it won't work.

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: where is #id ? looks like you are looking for dynamic event binding which can be done using .on click bindng...

Comment: With this immediate event model, $(..).click applies to *that, and only that* set of elements. This element is overwritten in the HTML clobber - use one of the delegated event handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [`$().on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), it is the new version of [`$().live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) which does exactly what you want:

```
$('body').on('mouseover','#id', function(){
    alert('true');
});
```